# Websocket on Reddit Endpoint to detect new post

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, websocket, socket.io

I have a JavaScript script to check if there is a new post in a certain subreddit. Reddit magicaly provides a JSON endpoint on every link. In this case I have the following endpoint:

https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/new.json?limit=1

I then used request module for node.js to get the specefic data I need eg domain, selftext, author and domain. However this changes every single time a new post is published and I therefore use a setInterval function to check every few seconds if a new post is released (Its like some sort of polling). I am saving every posts unique id to mongo to prevent double posting since that would assume every post is new on every request.

*So the structure is something like:*

```
setInterval(function () {
    request({
        uri: redditEndpoint,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {}) });

// I then save the data sent to mongo as unique to prevent double posting

// I consume the data here

}, 1000);
```

I would like to move away from this method and move over to websockets. However I am not sure how to correctly implement a websocket on such an endpoint, preferably with socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That websocket endpoint would need to be provided by the server - in this case from the reddit server. You can't create a websocket connection to a random server which does not offer websocket support.

The only thing you could do is build a proxy server, which polls the reddit server for new events (like what you are currently doing) and which then offers a websocket endpoint itself for other clients.

Comment: I found rockets.cc, and I intend to provide such a service soon!